# Cannot build HMS Core plugin ReactNative for Huawei P10

Tags: java, android, react-native, huawei-mobile-services

I am trying to build the app via npx react-native run-android. Everything seems to go well, the build ends up to 100% and the application is installed on the device. At the same time Metro Bundler was launched which also loaded up to 100%. However, the application crashes immediately when I tap to start it. I have captured the logs with adb which are shared below.

```
06-25 10:07:58.403  8200  8200 I HMSSDK_BaseAdapter: baseCallBack.onComplete
    06-25 10:07:58.404  8200  8200 I HMSSDK_HmsClient: receive msg status_code:0, error_code6003, api_name:push.gettoken, app_id:104458357|, pkg_name:my.app.package, session_id:*, transaction_id:104458357ttoken20210625100757996945883, resolution:null
    06-25 10:07:58.405  8200  8200 E HMSSDK_HmsInstanceId: TokenTask failed, ErrorCode: 6003
    06-25 10:07:58.408  8200  9162 E HMSSDK_AutoInit: Push init failed
    06-25 10:07:58.409  8200  9162 I HMSSDK_RemoteService: remote service bind service start
    06-25 10:07:58.423  8200  8200 I HMSSDK_HmsMessageService: start to bind
    06-25 10:07:58.425  1427  1815 D SmartHeartBeat: isPendingAlarm, false, pkg:com.android.deskclock, action:com.android.deskclock.ALARM_ALERT,not pending alarm with AlarmClockInfo
    06-25 10:07:58.425  1427  2392 V ActivityTaskManager: Activity idle: Token{a620457 ActivityRecord{6e892ac u0 my.app.package/.MainActivity t637}}
    06-25 10:07:58.425  8200  8200 I HMSSDK_RemoteService: remote service onConnected
    06-25 10:07:58.426  1427  1815 I JobScheduler.Time: realNextJobExpiredElapsedMillis: 814102
    06-25 10:07:58.426  8200  8200 I HMSSDK_RemoteService: remote service unbindservice
    06-25 10:07:58.428  8200  8200 I HMSSDK_HmsMessageService: handle message start 
    06-25 10:07:58.429  8200  8200 I HMSSDK_HmsMessageService: onNewToken
    06-25 10:07:58.429  1427  1815 D SmartHeartBeat: isPendingAlarm, false, pkg:com.android.deskclock, action:com.android.deskclock.ALARM_ALERT,not pending alarm with AlarmClockInfo
    06-25 10:07:58.430  1427  1815 I JobScheduler.Time: realNextDelayExpiredElapsedMillis: 813602
    06-25 10:07:58.430  8200  8200 I HMSSDK_HmsMessageService: doOnNewToken:transactionId = null , internalCode = 6003,subjectId:null,proxyType:null
    06-25 10:07:58.430  8200  8200 I HMSSDK_HmsMessageService: Apply token failed, subId: null
    06-25 10:07:58.432  8200  8200 I HMSSDK_HmsMessageService: onTokenError to host app.
    06-25 10:07:58.432  8200  8200 W HmsPushMessageService: ** onTokenError **
    06-25 10:07:58.433  8200  8200 I BlockMonitor: dispatchingThrewException In MainThread
    06-25 10:07:58.433  8200  8200 D AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
    06-25 10:07:58.434  8200  8200 I QarthLog: [PatchStore] createDisableExceptionQarthFile
    06-25 10:07:58.434  8200  8200 I QarthLog: [PatchStore] create disable file for my.app.package uid is 10173
    --------- beginning of crash
    06-25 10:07:58.435  8200  8200 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    06-25 10:07:58.435  8200  8200 E AndroidRuntime: Process: my.app.package, PID: 8200
    06-25 10:07:58.435  8200  8200 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Context android.content.Context.getApplicationContext()' on a null object reference
    06-25 10:07:58.435  8200  8200 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.huawei.hms.rn.push.logger.HMSLogger.getInstance(HMSLogger.java:100)
    06-25 10:07:58.435  8200  8200 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.huawei.hms.rn.push.remote.HmsPushMessageService.onTokenError(HmsPushMessageService.java:107)
    06-25 10:07:58.435  8200  8200 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.huawei.hms.push.HmsMessageService.a(HmsMessageService.java:34)
    06-25 10:07:58.435  8200  8200 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.huawei.hms.push.HmsMessageService.a(HmsMessageService.java:29)
    06-25 10:07:58.435  8200  8200 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.huawei.hms.push.HmsMessageService.handleIntentMessage(HmsMessageService.java:7)
    06-25 10:07:58.435  8200  8200 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.huawei.hms.push.HmsMessageService$a.handleMessage(HmsMessageService.java:7)
    06-25 10:07:58.435  8200  8200 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
    06-25 10:07:58.435  8200  8200 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:219)
    06-25 10:07:58.435  8200  8200 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8349)
    06-25 10:07:58.435  8200  8200 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    06-25 10:07:58.435  8200  8200 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:513)
    06-25 10:07:58.435  8200  8200 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1055)
    06-25 10:07:58.436  1427  9266 I DropBoxManagerService: add tag=data_app_crash isTagEnabled=true flags=0x2
    06-25 10:07:58.436  1427  9265 I QarthDisFileCreator: pattern not match
    06-25 10:07:58.442  1427  2026 E WifiService: enforceCanAccessScanResults: hiding ssid and bssidUID 10173 has no location permission
    06-25 10:07:58.443   933  3795 E         : FaultDetect: FaultEngineTracePrintf return.
    06-25 10:07:58.444  8200  8200 I HwApiCacheMangerEx: apicache path=/storage/emulated/0 state=mounted key=my.app.package#10173#0
    06-25 10:07:58.444  8200  8200 I HwApiCacheMangerEx: need clear apicache,because volumes changed,oldCnt=1 newCnt=1
    06-25 10:07:58.444   933  3794 E         : FaultDetect: DumptoolPrintf return.
    06-25 10:07:58.444   933  3795 E         : FaultDetect: FaultEngineTracePrintf return.
    06-25 10:07:58.444   933  3794 E         : FaultDetect: FaultEngineTracePrintf return.
    06-25 10:07:58.444   933  3795 E         : FaultDetect: DumptoolPrintf return.
    06-25 10:07:58.444   933  3794 E         : FaultDetect: FaultEngineTracePrintf return.
    06-25 10:07:58.444   933  3794 E         : FaultDetect: DumptoolPrintf return.
    06-25 10:07:58.444   933  3794 E         : FaultDetect: DumptoolPrintf return.
    06-25 10:07:58.444   933  3794 E         : FaultDetect: FaultEngineTracePrintf return.
    06-25 10:07:58.444  8200  8200 I HwApiCacheMangerEx: apicache path=/storage/emulated/0 state=mounted key=my.app.package#10173#256
    06-25 10:07:58.444  8200  8200 I HwApiCacheMangerEx: need clear apicache,because volumes changed,oldCnt=1 newCnt=1
    06-25 10:07:58.445   933  3794 E         : FaultDetect: DumptoolPrintf return.
    06-25 10:07:58.445   933  3794 E         : FaultDetect: FaultEngineTracePrintf return.
    06-25 10:07:58.445   933  3794 E         : FaultDetect: FaultEngineTracePrintf return.
    06-25 10:07:58.445   933  3794 E         : FaultDetect: DumptoolPrintf return.
    06-25 10:07:58.445   933  3794 E         : FaultDetect: FaultEngineTracePrintf return.
    06-25 10:07:58.445  8200  8200 I HwApiCacheMangerEx: apicache path=/storage/emulated/0 state=mounted key=my.app.package#10173#0
    06-25 10:07:58.445  8200  8200 I HwApiCacheMangerEx: need clear apicache,because volumes changed,oldCnt=1 newCnt=1
    06-25 10:07:58.445   933  7249 E         : FaultDetect: DumptoolPrintf return.
    06-25 10:07:58.445   933  7249 E         : FaultDetect: DumptoolPrintf return.
    06-25 10:07:58.445   933  7249 E         : FaultDetect: FaultEngineTracePrintf return.
    06-25 10:07:58.446  8200  8200 I HwApiCacheMangerEx: apicache path=/storage/emulated/0 state=mounted key=my.app.package#10173#256
    06-25 10:07:58.446  8200  8200 I HwApiCacheMangerEx: need clear apicache,because volumes changed,oldCnt=1 newCnt=1
    06-25 10:07:58.446   933  7249 E         : FaultDetect: DumptoolPrintf return.
    06-25 10:07:58.446   933  7249 I chatty  : uid=0(root) RFD_TASK2 identical 2 lines
    06-25 10:07:58.446   933  7249 E         : FaultDetect: DumptoolPrintf return.
    06-25 10:07:58.446  8200  8200 I HwApiCacheMangerEx: apicache path=/storage/emulated/0 state=mounted key=my.app.package#10173#0
    06-25 10:07:58.446  8200  8200 I HwApiCacheMangerEx: need clear apicache,because volumes changed,oldCnt=1 newCnt=1
    06-25 10:07:58.447  8200  8200 I HwApiCacheMangerEx: apicache path=/storage/emulated/0 state=mounted key=my.app.package#10173#256
    06-25 10:07:58.447  8200  8200 I HwApiCacheMangerEx: need clear apicache,because volumes changed,oldCnt=1 newCnt=1
    06-25 10:07:58.447   933  7249 E         : FaultDetect: DumptoolPrintf return.
    06-25 10:07:58.448   933  7249 I chatty  : uid=0(root) RFD_TASK2 identical 4 lines
    06-25 10:07:58.449   933  7249 E         : FaultDetect: DumptoolPrintf return.
    06-25 10:07:58.450  2007  2182 E         : [ZeroHung]zrhung_get_config: Get config failed for wp[0x0008]
    06-25 10:07:58.450  2007  9261 I HttpHelper: [I/HMSCore/HttpHelper 2007:303 SourceFile:83] Call execute end.
    06-25 10:07:58.450  2007  3496 D LogWrite: wtf Exception
    06-25 10:07:58.450  2007  9261 E OpenGWTask: [E/HMSCore/OpenGWTask 2007:303 SourceFile:330] onPostExecute, get scope failed, certFingerprint is empty, appID:104458357, resultDesc:httpCode=200,nspStatus=0,errorText=,jsonResult=OK
    06-25 10:07:58.450  2007  3496 D LogWrite: wtf Exception
    06-25 10:07:58.451   933  7249 E         : FaultDetect: DumptoolPrintf return.
    06-25 10:07:58.451  2007  6660 I NetworkSdk_HianalyticsHelper: [I/HMSCore/NetworkSdk_HianalyticsHelper 2007:198 SourceFile:28] Core-Connect-6 -->NetworkKit_report_ha_0|null|com.huawei.hms.framework.common.hianalytics.HianalyticsHelper|isEnableReportNoSeed|9|user experience involved needs to be opened
    06-25 10:07:58.451  2007  6660 I NetworkSdk_DefaultRCEventListener: [I/HMSCore/NetworkSdk_DefaultRCEventListener 2007:198 SourceFile:28] Core-Connect-6 -->NetworkKit_report_ha_0|SourceFile|bmg|bs|278|HianalyticsHelper report disable
```

Taking a look at the code inside the HMS Core node modules, I tried to figure out what it could be. It seems that the context is not ready yet and that the Activity takes longer to be "ready to use", while the plugin tries to access it too soon. Regardless of whether my hypothesis is correct or not, I have no idea how to solve this problem.

```
/**
 * Returns the instance of this class.
 *
 * @param context Context object
 * @return HMSLogger instance
 */
public static synchronized HMSLogger getInstance(final Context context) {
    if (instance == null) {
        synchronized (HMSLogger.class) {
            if (instance == null) {
                instance = new HMSLogger(context.getApplicationContext());
            }
        }
    }
    return instance;
}
```

The configuration of the environment is this:

- nodejs: v10.18
- @hmscore/react-native-hms-push: ^5.1.1-301
- react-native: 0.63.2

I followed installation instruction from [Huawei official documentation](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-Guides/integraternmodule-0000001050157791).

Comment: hi@shogitai,You are advised to debug and check whether an empty context object is transferred.